# swift 3.0 folding-cell library table not showing

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, swift3, ios10, xcode8

I am using https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell library into my `Swift 3.0` projects. It works nice without any editing or changing on `storyboard/auto layout` changing.

I faced some issues when tried to:

1. Add few IBOUTLET (in DemoCell.swift)
2. Add Data to them (in DemoCell's didSet() method)

Now the view is blank. But i can scroll the `tableview`(it is just not showing), can click and can see folded cell perfectly.

I tried to add constrains as it given in documentation. I get fatal crash.

I am using `Xcode 8`, `swift 3.0`. This is happen always even when i download the fresh source code and add new `uilabel` or anything change on `storyboard`.

Does anybody tried this library recently ?

Blank Screenshot:

[image]

When click in the cell, Other cell is hidden.But clickable.

[image]

Foreground view:

[image]

Comment: No solution still :(

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with the library. Now its solved.

Thread: https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell/issues/69#event-819438913